# File Download from Ext AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

HI I get a tar file in response Text for the Ext AJAX i need to convert that into a file and download. please let me know any way.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
             url : 'download.do',
             method:'POST',
             async:false,
             useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
             cors: true,
             params : configRequest.parameters,
             scope : this,
             success : configRequest.success?configRequest.success:function(response){
                    var res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    if(res.result && res.result=='error'){
                        this.ajaxErrorDisplay(res.err);
                    } }, failure : configRequest.failure?configRequest.failure:function(msg){}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden form and then submit try this code.

```
getDownloadForm: function(url, requestParams) {
        var hiddenForm = Ext.getCmp('download-file-excel-form');
        if (!hiddenForm) {
            hiddenForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
              title:'hiddenForm',
              id: 'download-file-excel-form',                             
              height:0,
              width: 0,
              hidden:true
            });
        }   

        hiddenForm.getForm().submit({
            url: url,
            standardSubmit: true,
            method: 'POST', 
            timeout: 120000,
            params: requestParams
        });
    }
```